# C++ STL::map containing STL::deque (cannot convert from 'void' to class*)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, deque

I get the following error when trying to assign a element from a deque to a user defined class.

```
    map<unsigned int, std::deque<Order*>>::iterator itBuyPrices =buyPrices.begin();
    Order *buyOrder;
    buyOrder = itBuyPrices->second.pop_back();
```

ERROR at the assignment line (3rd line):
Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'void' to 'Order *'

Comment: Look up what `pop_back` returns.  It'll surprise you.

Comment: The fix is to erase the `pop_` characters from that third line of code, then you will be left with `back()`,

Comment: Thank you  ( i feel silly for asking this)

Answer (score 0):

`deque::pop_back()` returns `void`, ie nothing.  You need to use `deque::back()` to access the last item in the queue before then calling `pop_back()` to remove it, eg:

```cpp
map<unsigned int, std::deque<Order*>>::iterator itBuyPrices = buyPrices.begin();
Order *buyOrder = itBuyPrices->second.back();
itBuyPrices->second.pop_back();
```